# Starting Email mentioning weather

Tags: word-choice, expressions

My boss asked me to translate an email into English and it starts with this sentence:

> Dear @@,
>   There will be cherry blossoms in Japan soon.

This is a literal translation. 
I think my translation might be awkward. 
Could you please help me to improve the sentence? 
Thank you.

Comment: Is this a common expression in Japanese? If so, what does it normally represent? Does it mean that it will be Spring soon?

Comment: @JohnGo-Soco  The original language is Korean and the writer wrote it to a Japanese person. It is common expression to say it will be spring soon.

Comment: The only issue relevant on ELU is whether 'cherry blossoms' should be substituted by the mass-noun usage 'cherry blossom', but there are plenty of ('pretend-count'?) tokens on the web ('pretend' because I think the plural-form is notional shorthand for 'cherry trees in blossom'). Going off-topic, (a) I'd choose 'cherry blossoms' as poetically acceptable here; (b) although it's a fixed expression in one language (as per your comment), it's not in English. But the literal translation does not jar at all: in fact, it sounds mellifluous, with a hint of Eastern romanticism. As seasons in the ...

Comment: US and UK largely correspond (spring is the time when trees blossom), the transferred meaning involved is merely a tiny step, and the implication involved in the translation is transparent. Don't hesitate to use it.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Thank you very much for your kind answer.